# Using permissions groups in Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to ask for a permission groups in manifest? For example: instead of asking for both the permission to read the calendar and write to the calendar, can he simply ask for the calendar permission group?

Comment: No you can't 1 permission can do every thing

Comment: Google created this ease the process so you can't request a single permission

Comment: so if i include of the calendar permissions in the manifest, the application will be automatically granted the entire calender permissions group? also during upgrade to 4.4 (where permissions groups was introduced) an application will get the permissions groups that each of her permissions belong to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can an Android developer ask for a permission groups in his manifest?

Not in the M Developer Preview. There is no `<uses-permission-group>`. And the [runtime permission model](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html) still works off of individual permissions, presumably to give the Android team flexibility for changing the permission groups (and what permissions they hold) over time.

Note that this could change by the time Android M ships in production form later in 2015.

Comment: so if i include one of the calendar permissions in the manifest, the application will be automatically granted the entire calender permissions group? also during upgrade to 4.4 (where permissions groups was introduced) an application will get the permissions groups that each of her permissions belong to?

Comment: @pulu: " if i include one of the calendar permissions in the manifest, the application will be automatically granted the entire calender permissions group?" -- not in the M Developer Preview, as you also have to ask for those at runtime via `checkSelfPermission()`. However, the user will grant them to you at the group level, at least in the current preview. "where permissions groups was introduced" -- permission groups have been around since Android 1.0.

Comment: @pulu: "an application will get the permissions groups that each of her permissions belong to?" -- the user control is at the group level for runtime permissions. However, you still have to ask for each individual permission in the manifest. AFAIK, if you request `READ_CALENDAR` but not `WRITE_CALENDAR` in the manifest, even if the user says "you can work with the calendar" via the runtime permission mechanism, you still cannot write to the calendar, because you did not ask for `WRITE_CALENDAR` in the manifest.

Comment: thanks for the detailed and fast response.i just want to make sure i understand you, for the first point if the user approves the permission when i try to use it the first permissions then when i will try the second permission it will be granted since the user already approved the groups during the previous request. for the second point  if i add to the manifest the second permission then the application will approved the permissions without the user having to approve that.

Comment: @pulu: "if the user approves the permission when i try to use it the first permissions then when i will try the second permission it will be granted since the user already approved the groups during the previous request" -- I have not tried that. `checkSelfPermission()` takes permissions, not groups, and I pass all the relevant permissions. "if i add to the manifest the second permission then the application will approved the permissions without the user having to approve that" -- I have not played with upgrading an app to have different permissions with the M Developer Preview.

Comment: so in order to use all the permissions that are part of a permission group we must declare all of them in the application manifest?

Comment: @pulu: That is what I recommend. First, you need to do that anyway, for the 99.999% of Android devices running less than Android M. Second, AFAIK, you need to do it even for Android M, as you should not be getting capabilities that you do not specifically request, at the permission level. Third, you may need it in the future, as Android could easily change further (e.g., a future set of Android Work managed profiles, akin to managed Chrome profiles, where enterprises allow and deny individual permissions, rather than permission groups).

Comment: Thanks again but is it true that if i declare a permission that is part of a permission group that the application was already approved then the user won't need to approve anything?

Comment: @pulu: That varies by distribution channel and installation method. And, as I have noted I have not played with upgrading an app to have different permissions with the M Developer Preview.